# For R a ring, if $x^n=x$ for all x∈R then R is commutative

Tags: gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

I came across the following Theorem on a paper I'm reading:

"If $R$ is a ring and $x^n=x$ for all $x\in R$ then $R$ is commutative"

However I have no idea of how to prove it. May I get some hints?

Comment: For $n > 1$ this is an old theorem of Jacobson. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/207757/what-are-applications-of-commutativity-theorems-for-rings.

Comment: And for $n=1$ it's false.

Comment: And for $n=0$ it’s trivial.

Comment: To be pedantic, the symbol $n$ in this post is undefined. In fact the correct statement of Jacobson's Theorem is "if $R$ is a ring, and for all $x \in R$ there exists an integer $n>1$ with $x^n=x$, then $R$ is commutative". It is difficult to prove and I don't advise attempting it. Try proving that $\forall x \in X\, x^2=x \Rightarrow R$ commutative, and if you find that easy, try proving $\forall x \in X\, x^3=x \Rightarrow R$ commutative, which is a starred exercise in Herstein's Topics in Algebra.

Comment: I don't think it's pedantic to say this. Without quantifier on $n$, this is unclear, and it's part of the (easy) efforts to make a post clear, to quantify so as to make a question clear. (Maybe it should be said that $R$ is supposed associative, since a large number of people use "ring" in a broader sense, and even for $n=2$ the conclusion fails without associativity.)

Comment: Notice this contains as a special case  Wedderburn's theorem that a finite division ring is a field so you shouldn't expect it to be trivial